# Single line GO(Batch) statement giving error in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have one question. I was creating below procedure temporary.

When I Execute it in below format it works fine:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Get_TableList_By_Name
@Proc_Name VARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name LIKE '%' + @Proc_Name + '%'
END 
GO
EXEC Get_TableList_By_Name 'norway'
GO
DROP PROCEDURE Get_TableList_By_Name 
GO
```

But when I execute same SQL in below format it giving error saying: "Incorrect syntax near 'GO'."

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Get_TableList_By_Name @Proc_Name VARCHAR(255) AS BEGIN SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name LIKE '%' + @Proc_Name + '%' END GO EXEC Get_TableList_By_Name 'norway' GO DROP PROCEDURE Get_TableList_By_Name GO

CREATE PROCEDURE Get_TableList_By_Name @Proc_Name VARCHAR(255) AS BEGIN SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name LIKE '%' + @Proc_Name + '%' END GO 1 EXEC Get_TableList_By_Name 'norway' GO 1 DROP PROCEDURE Get_TableList_By_Name GO 1
```

How to write same SQL with GO statement in single line? 
Is it possible? If not then Why?

Thanks,
Vishal

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [GO (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28GO_TSQL%29;k%28SQL11.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1%29;k%28SQL11.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1%29;k%28MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT%29;k%28DevLang-TSQL%29&rd=true)

> A Transact-SQL statement cannot occupy the same line as a GO command.
>   However, the line can contain comments.

So Go needs to be on its own line, except for comments.

Comment: Thanks Astander.
So there is no way to write it on single line?

Comment: There cannot be a comment after GO in the same line either ...

Answer (score 4):

'GO' is not a SQL command. It is a batch terminator recognized by tools
like Query Analyzer, SSMS, SQLCMD, etc. These tools generally require the
GO to be on a separate line and send the preceding SQL statements as a batch
to SQL Server when the GO is encountered

GO Statement must be written in new line as it is not T-SQL command. 
T-SQL statement can not occupy the same line as GO. GO statement can contain comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute this:

```
EXEC   SP_COMMAND 1,2;
EXEC   SP_COMMAND 2,2;
EXEC   SP_COMMAND 3,2;
```

Set EXEC Bebore sp and ';' for end statement
then
select all code (SSMS) and press f5 o exec all you code by other thecnic.