# Shortcut for search functionality in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to create shortcut for below SQL code

```
DECLARE @Proc_Name VARCHAR(255)
SET @Proc_Name ='norway'
SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name LIKE '%' + @Proc_Name + '%'
```

Right now I am using below shortcut for same
[image]

Then I type {LIKE '%test%'} and press Ctrl+8.

But I want to make it more simplified format(Like I can type {test} and press Ctrl+8) so that I can use it quickly.

I was trying same in different way like creating proc > then execute > and drop it on shortcut key press. For more info please visit below link:

[Single line GO(Batch) statement giving error in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24133099/single-line-gobatch-statement-giving-error-in-sql-server/)

Thanks,

Vishal

Answer (score 0):

I have the following stored proc that I added to the Master db on my SQL Server

```
USE [master]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_FindAllReferences]
@targetText nvarchar(128)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @origdb nvarchar(128)
    select @origdb = db_name()

    declare @sql nvarchar(1000)

    set @sql = 'USE [' + @origdb +'];' 
    set @sql += 'select object_name(m.object_id), m.* '
    set @sql += 'from sys.sql_modules m  where m.definition like N' + CHAR(39) + '%' + @targetText + '%' + CHAR(39)

    exec (@sql)

    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
END
```

Then I have added `dbo.SP_FindAllReferences` to one of my SSMS keyboard shortcuts so that I can search for text in the context of any DB on my server.

For example, if I type **user** in a SSMS query window, highlight it and press the shortcut combo, then I get a list of every stored proc in the current database that contains **user**

If you replace my select with

```
set @sql = 'USE [' + @origdb +'];' 
set @sql += 'Select * FROM sys.tables WHERE name LIKE N' + CHAR(39) + '%' + @targetText + '%' + CHAR(39)
```

then you be able to achieve your goal.

Comment: DeanOC: Thank you!!! I Really appreciate your approach. It's Great.
But in my case I don't have access to Master to perform this operation. So I was trying to create and execute and drop proc on single Key, in such way nobody will come to know that I have created some procedure for personal use(Since it has been dropped once it used). Sorry to say need any other approach.. But your approach is owsome.